# Delete an NSManaged Object

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I've been trying to delete an NSManagedObject.
This is my code:

```
    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MyEnt")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF = %@", EnttoDelete.objectID)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0 {

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                print ("Ent found")                    
                context.delete(result)

                 do {
                 try context.save()
                 } catch {
                 print("failed to delete")
                 }

            }

        }


    } catch {

        print ("Error in do")
    }
}
```

Has you see I have de Entitie do be deleted (EnttoDelete) and therefor it's ID (EnttoDelete.objectID).
Now I've researchedm even in stackoverflow and I think this should work. But it's not.
How can I delete desired entitie?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does `results` have any content? If not, then there is a problem with your request and/or predicate.

Comment: Yes. I done exactly the same thing with other entitie and it worked. The difference was that I used a attribute and not the objectID. In this case it doesn't work.... However using the code I copied down, it works...

Comment: You could also try `existingObjectWithID` to get the enitiy with a particular ID and then delete it.

Comment: In Swift 3 it would be `existingObject(with objectID: NSManagedObjectID)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I sort this, doing a different thing:

```
    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var thisID: NSManagedObjectID = (thatLand?.objectID)!
    let object = context.object(with: thisID)
    context.delete(object)

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("failed to delete")
    }
```

I thinks it's the better solution. Not sure though!